# Show Cell Range on UserForm; then update

Tags: vba, excel

I've been using a crude method to help the user update some cells - by having them in a sheet. Is there any way I can display the various ranges in a userform, one by one, then have the user update them, click a button and move onto the next one?

Essentially, can I have Excel automatically generate an input form based on a range? The process of updating and saving back to the sheet I can do; it's the production of the correct form that I can't.

Comment: "I've been using a crude method to help the user update some cells - by having them in a sheet." - where else can you have cells than on a sheet?

Comment: Well, I meant that there are sections of the worksheet used as data sources, and the user must navigate themselves to them to update them. It's not very pretty or practical!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to do this, but the only way I can think of is to make a userform that automatically populates itself based on a range passed in.  This way you could have different macros in Excel that call the form to populate based on different ranges.  I built a proof of concept Excel file for trying this, and it seems to work, the only issue I can think of being that you need to figure out a way to tell the user what input field is what.

I think what needs to be done is to add controls programmatically to a userform (I name the textboxes as the cell address it's going to populate) then when the form is closed loop through all the textboxes and populate the cells with the textbox values.

You can see what I did at:
https://my.syncplicity.com/share/uicgbs3rl0/InputForm.xls

I think all that would need to be done is for you to work out how to add labels for the textboxes, and make sure the form is resized based on the controls you add...

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite shure what you are looking for, but you could insert a second sheet and use it as a "form". An other way could be a dialog box with an input field.

Either way, you present the cells you want the user to change one by one, using a vba-function. You implement a "previous field" and a "next field" button, so the user can step through the range of cells. If the user hits "next field", you save his input and take the next cell from a previous defined range of cells.

You could have a "config field" in which you define the range of cells you want to change.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid setting up input fields (unless it's generated automatically somehow by Excel), as there are 10 data ranges to be updated.

I also want to show the whole range at once, as it'll be much easier on the user to input the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty rough and old-fashioned but if you have the data in standard list format - i.e. column headers in the first row of your range and then one record of data in each row below -  then selecting a cell within the range and going `Data > Form` will give you a crude input form with roughly the functionality you need.

You can also do this in VBA by calling the `ShowDataForm` method of the appropriate worksheet. Just select a cell within whichever range you need first. The macro will remain paused until the user closes the data form